# Unable to start activity componentinfo---Nullpointer exception

Tags: android

When I press the "show" button(btnshow) it shows the error unable to start activity component info  & Nullpointer Exception.How can i solve this problem.plz help me.....

Mainactivity.java

```
    package com.mamun.sqltest;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;




    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        private Button add, delete, update, show, search;
        private EditText etname, etaddress, etcell, etsearch;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
            delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndelete);
            update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnupdate);
            show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnshow);
            search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsearch);

            etname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etname);
            etaddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etaddress);
            etcell = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etcell);
            etsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etsearch);

            add.setOnClickListener(this);
            delete.setOnClickListener(this);
            update.setOnClickListener(this);
            show.setOnClickListener(this);
            search.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnadd:
                boolean didItwork = true;
                try {
                    String name = etname.getText().toString();
                    String address = etaddress.getText().toString();
                    String cell = etcell.getText().toString();

                    Dbtrial entry = new Dbtrial(MainActivity.this);
                    entry.open();
                    entry.createEntry(name, address, cell);
                    entry.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    didItwork = false;

                    String error = e.toString();
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Error found");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText(error);
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();
                } finally {
                    if (didItwork) {
                        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                        d.setTitle("Saved");
                        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                        tv.setText("Sucess");
                        d.setContentView(tv);
                        d.show();
                    }
                }

                break;
            case R.id.btndelete:
                try{String sRow1 = etsearch.getText().toString();
                long lRow1 = Long.parseLong(sRow1); 

                Dbtrial ex1 = new  Dbtrial(this);
                ex1.open();
                ex1.deleteEntry(lRow1);
                ex1.close();
                }catch (Exception e) {


                    String error = e.toString();
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Error found");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText(error);
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.btnupdate:
                try{
                    String sRow = etsearch.getText().toString();
                long lRow= Long.parseLong(sRow); 

                String upname = etname.getText().toString();
                String upaddress = etaddress.getText().toString();
                String upcell = etcell.getText().toString();
                Dbtrial ex = new  Dbtrial(this);
                ex.open();
                ex.updateEntry(lRow,upname,upaddress,upcell);
                ex.close();
            }catch (Exception e) {


                String error = e.toString();
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Error found");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(error);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }

                break;
            case R.id.btnshow:
                Intent i = new Intent(this,Sqlview.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            case R.id.btnsearch:
                try {
                    String s = etsearch.getText().toString();

                long l= Long.parseLong(s);
                Dbtrial hon = new Dbtrial(this);
                hon.open();
                String returnedNamed = hon.getName(l);
                String returnedAddress = hon.getAddress(l);
                String returnedCell = hon.getCell(l);
                hon.close();


                etname.setText(returnedNamed);
                etaddress.setText(returnedAddress);
                etcell.setText(returnedCell);

                }catch (Exception e) {


                    String error = e.toString();
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Error found");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText(error);
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();
                }



                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }

    }
```

***Dbtrial.java***

```
package com.mamun.sqltest;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Dbtrial {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String KEY_CELL = "cell";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Infodb";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Info";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
            + " INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME
            + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + KEY_CELL + " NUMBER NOT NULL );");

}

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public Dbtrial(Context c) {

        ourContext = c;
    }

    public Dbtrial open() throws SQLException {
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public long createEntry(String name, String address, String cell) {


// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            cv.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
            cv.put(KEY_CELL, cell);
            return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

    }

    public String getData() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_ADDRESS,
                KEY_CELL };//
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        String result = "";

        int iId = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            result = result + c.getString(iId) + "\n";//
        }
        return result;
    }

    public String getName(long l) throws SQLException {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_ADDRESS,
                KEY_CELL };//
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "="
                + l, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            String name = c.getString(1);
            return name;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getAddress(long l) throws SQLException {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_ADDRESS,
                KEY_CELL };//
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "="
                + l, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            String address = c.getString(2);
            return address;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getCell(long l) throws SQLException {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_ADDRESS,
                KEY_CELL };//
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "="
                + l, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            String cell = c.getString(3);
            return cell;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void updateEntry(long lRow, String upname, String upaddress,
            String upcell) throws SQLException {
        ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
        cvUpdate.put(KEY_NAME, upname);
        cvUpdate.put(KEY_ADDRESS, upaddress);
        cvUpdate.put(KEY_CELL, upcell);
        ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_ROWID + "=" + lRow,
                null);
    }

    public void deleteEntry(long lRow1) throws SQLException {
        ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + lRow1, null);

    }

    public String getData2() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_ADDRESS,
                KEY_CELL };//
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        String result = "";

        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            result = result + c.getString(iName) + "\n";//
        }
        return result;

    }

    public String getData3() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_ADDRESS,
                KEY_CELL };//
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        String result = "";

        int iAddress = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ADDRESS);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            result = result + c.getString(iAddress) + "\n";
        }
        return result;

    }

    public String getData4() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_ADDRESS,
                KEY_CELL };//
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        String result = "";

        int iCell = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CELL);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            result = result + c.getString(iCell) + "\n";
        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

***Sqlview.java***

```
 package com.mamun.sqltest;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class Sqlview extends Activity {

    // data source
    private String alldata;
    private Dbtrial dbAdapter;

    // adapter
    private DataAdapter adapter;

    // view
    private ListView lvinfo;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sqlview);

        // //
        dbAdapter = new Dbtrial(this);
        dbAdapter.open();
        alldata = dbAdapter.getData();
        dbAdapter.close();

        lvinfo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvinfo);
        adapter = new DataAdapter(this, alldata);
        lvinfo.setAdapter(adapter);


        lvinfo.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listview, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected Book: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


    }

}
```

****DataAdapter****

```
 package com.mamun.sqltest;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class DataAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<Dbtrial>{



    private Activity context;
    private static ArrayList<Dbtrial> items;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public DataAdapter(Context context, String alldata) {
        super(context, R.layout.info_item, items);
        this.context=(Activity)context;
        this.items=items;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v=convertView;
        if(v==null)
        {
            // create new view
            inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
            v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_item, null);

            TextView tvid=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvid);
            TextView tvname=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvname);
            TextView tvaddress=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvaddress);
            TextView tvcell=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvcell);

            Dbtrial b=items.get(position);
            tvid.setText(b.getData());
            tvname.setText(b.getData2());
            tvaddress.setText(b.getData3());
            tvcell.setText(b.getData4());

            tvname.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "I am a title", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

        }
        else
        {

        }

        return v;
    }



}
```

xml files are:

*activity_main.xml*`

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etaddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cell"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etcell"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="phone" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnadd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/btn_add" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btndelete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Delete" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnupdate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Update" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnshow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Show" />
        </TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search here"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etsearch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="search by id"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnsearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

***sqlview.xml***

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvinfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

****info_item.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Id"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvaddress"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="address" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
              />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="name"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvcell"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="cell" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="right"/>

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

***LogCat***

```
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mamun.sqltest/com.mamun.sqltest.Sqlview}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:462)
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at com.mamun.sqltest.Sqlview.onCreate(Sqlview.java:38)
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-07 07:42:46.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: post the stack trace and post only the relevant parts.

Comment: just when show button is pressed which is in the activity_main.xml then shows the above error.can u help @ Raghunandan

Comment: @user3076959 post the stacktrace need to know which line causes NPE and cut down your code to relevant part.

Comment: log Cat is posted@ Imtiyaz Khalani

Comment: what i have to do in getCount(); method i really can't understand.can u explain or complete the project plz..@Raghunandan

Comment: @user3076959 just try `@Override public int getCount(){return items.size();}` in your adapter and make sure `alldata` has the data retrieved from database

Comment: same thing is happening@Raghunandan

Comment: @user3076959  R u sure `alldata` is populated? NPE @ `ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)`

Comment: @user3076959 laalto is right `super(context, R.layout.info_item, items);` items is null.

Answer (score 1):

The `items` you pass to `ArrayAdapter` super constructor is `null`.

Comment: But how can I show  data in listview.I got confused when all others button are working except "show" button.plz give an exact solution so that I can complete my project @laalto

Answer (score 0):

I feel issue is with `Dbtrial` constructor. you are opening database in write mode `ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();` and in `getData()` you are reading database using `querymethod`. To read data from database it should open in readable mode. That is reason it returns empty data to `alldata = dbAdapter.getData();` and will not initialize adapter and will throw error.

Comment: I got the same error when I open in readable mode also.Is there any way to solve it @Virtual Reality Systems

Comment: error occurred at 38th line of your `Sqlview` class, which is `lvinfo.setAdapter(adapter);` there might be two reason either adapter is not initialized due to no data fetched from database or your listview object is not initalized properly. if data is coming from database try to clean your project. Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: adapter & listview object is initialized but still now its not working

Comment: try to print `alldata` value and check if it is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the space after NUMBER NOT NULL